# sending parameters to another website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I use Asp.Net Mvc4. I need to transfer some data to another web site.I want to explain:

There is a site that people query their salaries on this site. For exmaple www.xsalary.com. People enter this site. They enter their identity number, year, month etc. infos to textboxes into this site. Then they click submit button and, the site shows their salary infos to them.

I have a personnel web application. I have personel's identity number etc. I show personnel salaries in a page. In this page, there is button.When someone click this button, application open the site that I explain above, and textboxes in this site is filled with my sending parameters identity number, year etc. infos.

I hope I can explain what I need. How can I do this in Mvc ? Is it possible ?
Thank in advance.

Comment: Your question is not much explanatory :(

Comment: I think you are looking for an API. Does that salary query website have an API? Even if it does not, you can integrate using Selenium which will be harder but it will do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

My idea would be. Put a @html.TextareaFor element on your main site. Connect this element with your Model. If the user push the submit button, you send the information from your textarea to your controller where you can query the Information from your database. Now you can put the salary information into another view.

Let the controller call the result view and show the user his salary information.

Comment: You're assuming that both applications run on the same DB...  An outside site may not have access to the DB, thus making it impossible to do this.